# k-nearest alg : how can I set K manually?

Tags: php, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

i want to predict a unlabeled item from K-NEAREST neighbour alg.
but in default K=1 from package machine learning readthedocs

how can I set K manually???

```
<?php
$samples = [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 1], [4, 1], [4, 2]];
$labels = ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no'];
$class = new KNearestNeighbors();
$class->train($samples, $labels);
$class->predict(1,7);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may further read in the [documentation](https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/machine-learning/classification/k-nearest-neighbors/), you may define `K` as following:

```
$class = new KNearestNeighbors($k=4);
```

Note that the default value of `K` is 3.